# how to install igraph package for python windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, python-wheel

I have downloaded the package and it is in `whl` file when I try to install it, i get this error

> C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install C:\Users\213546472\Downloads\python_igraph-0.7.1.post6-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl
>   python_igraph-0.7.1.post6-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
>   Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\213546472\pip\pip.log

Comment: `pip install python-igraph`

Answer (score 0):

You're installing 64-bit wheel. Check that your Python is version 3.4 64 bit. If not — download a proper wheel (different Python version or 32 bit wheel).

Answer (score -1):

Use cmd: pip install python-igraph
Otherwise,
Try using a precompiled binary here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-igraph

Choose the proper version, use pip and type:

python -m pip install path/to/igraph.whl
Do not change the wheel name. Make sure you have pip, wheel and setuptools installed.